# Ubuntu 20.04 - how to ungroup apps in dock?

Tags: 20.04, dock

I'm trying to **ungroup the same app instances** in the dock but with no luck (**Ubuntu 20.04**).

For example, I launched two instances of the Krusader and they are grouped in the same icon, which is very inconvenient. Is it possible to show each instance as a separate icon in the dock for easier switching between them?
I've found solutions for previous Ubuntu versions, but they seem to be not working in Ubuntu 20...

[image]

Comment: Hello. there is no such version of Ubuntu as 20.

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu Core 20 ?  As the releases using the *year* format are different products to the *year.month*, and you mention both 20 & 20.04 which are different systems.  Please clarify.

Comment: I mean simple 20.04.4 LTS - latest LTS release available

Comment: You will quickly have very many icons in the dock. Anyway, I do not think this is possible with the Ubuntu dock. It is possible, however, in the "Dash to Panel" extension, that places the icon on a bar at the bottom like in MS Windows.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Kar19 Unfortunately no

Answer (score -1):

You need to create shortcut in path ./local/share/applications. Then you can comment #StartupWMClass=xxx. The program will be started without group icon.

Comment: please tell us how will that ungroup icons in dock